# How to position Material UI badge near IconButton in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, user-experience

How can I solve the issue of positioning the badge content to be near the IconButton in Material UI ?

I've tried to disableRipple but it doesn't work!

Ugly
[image]

```
     <Badge badgeContent={4} color="primary">
          <IconButton
            disableFocusRipple
            disableRipple
            style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
          >
            <MailIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Badge>
```

How I want to appear
[image]

If I don't use IconButton everything is okay, but I need Icon Button!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the IconButton outside of the Badge

```
 <IconButton style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
      <Badge badgeContent={4} color="primary">
           <MailIcon />
      </Badge>
   </IconButton>
```

Result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use overlap="circular" props on IconButton

```
<Badge variant="dot" overlap="circular">
  <IconButton iconPath={mdiBellOutline} iconSize={1.2} />
</Badge>
```